# jquery-scrollify - setHeight false

Tags: jquery-scrollify

When I have the setHeight: true it adds white space below most of my divs. When it is set to false, it breaks the scroll.

Is this expected behavior? I don't want all my divs to equal the same height.

Comment: Could you please add more information in your question, for example, add what you have tried already.

Comment: I have tried setting setHeight: to false, changed the div height to 100%, changed the div height to auto.